# WWVB Antenna receiver 1st Amplifier stage, no signal

Tags: amplifier, antenna, receiver

I made a high input impedance JFET CS amp as the 1st amplifier stage for a 60kHz Loopstick Antenna. I am using an RF JFET (J211) and ceramic capacitors.

[image]

The only signal I see is a **60Hz** sine wave that is present even when the amplifier is turned off.

I am unsure what to do at this point. I don't know if a I need a larger Antenna or if I am doing something wrong in trying to detect this signal. WWVB *is* particularly weak where I'm at as well.

Comment: What you should do is test your amplifier with a signal generator that generates a signal you can see, and that you can gradually turn down to the levels you expect to get from the antenna. But if you're seeing a lot of 60 Hz, then you have grounding issues that you need to address first.

Comment: How do you know that the antenna is tuned correctly? Test with a signal generator and a transmitting loop, some distance away, and check that the received signal peaks near 60 kHz. If you see mains buzz... Are you powering this from the mains - try a battery? Note that the expected voltage from WWV may be only a few tens of micro volts.

Comment: Those 10 microfarad caps are way way too big .Try 10 nanofarad and you will see a little less 60HZ so it might be easier to see your 60KHz

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need to check your gnd, then decouple your +12V power supply to get rid of that 60hz mains humm.

Next, Let's try to bias that depletion-mode JFET to around -1.5Vgs to keep it operating well within its linear region.

Finally, add a 60Khz tank between Vpos and your drain to narrow the bandwidth of your amp.

I'm envisioning something like:
[image: Modified Preamp]

Comment: If you want a little more gain (and narrower bandwidth) from this circuit, you could place another 60Khz tank between the incoming signal trace & the 3M pull-down/bias resistor.

Comment: I just revised the diagram due to improper placement of a gate bias resistor & changed coupling capacitors' values to match @Autistic 's suggestion from OP comment.

Comment: It works! I tied 2 of theses amplifiers together and I am able to see a 20mV 60kHz On/Off signal. Thats pretty good considering I cant get FM radio or cell phone reception where I am at.

Comment: @Tony if you want, we could probably come up with some similar preamps for AM/FM radio frequencies & see if you can pull a few of those in. Cell phoes, however, (according to Wilson Cellular) use TDMA algorythms, so even with better signal amplification, the time delay would likely be too long for a cell tower to accept your link.