# How to modulate a LED to send data and recieve with a photodiode

Tags: microcontroller, led, modulation

What is the concept of modulating a light source (white led, IR led, etc) to send data and then demodulating it with a photodiode back into data?

I am wanting to experiment with trying to use IR/White diodes to send data at various frequencies above 1mhz over open air. I know some pre-existing parts exist such as 36khz IR receivers, but I am wanting to understand the background theory of how the TX and RX sides fit together with the various steps/parts so that I can reproduce it and then see if I can modify it to work at higher frequencies or further ranges.

I have a basic understanding of the process works (for instance how remotes work), but an in depth explanation for the TX/RX sides would be helpful from a micro controller toggling the TX LED all the way to a micro controller RXing the data with the necessary parts that may be required on both ends (if applicable). Explanations about the actual protocol specifics of the data transfer can be left out.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't bother trying white LEDs. They have a phosphor coating which has a persistence in the 10's of milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for this. I also read something about this as well, but during the same reading material they claim there was a phosphor-less white LED. Although I will likely use an IR (or possibly red) since that seems the most popular.

Comment: A phosphor-free "white" LED will just be a red, a green and a blue LED mounted together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should start with maybe 100KHz before trying to push the envelope all the way to 1MHz. As you increase the pulse frequency, you'll run into a 'brick wall' at the limit of the LED's diode switching & light emission pulsing frequency.

While there are super-fast diodes/lasers used for fibre transmission; not all LEDs will function at MHz speeds.

As for the actual modulation of the light; you can choose between AM, FM, OOK, or PWM for encoding data into your pulses. While I could write several paragraphs on using each in this instance, I don't think I would be doing much better than the respective Wikipedia articles, so I'll just refer you to them here.

Once you've decided on your baseband pulse frequency & your modulation method, your MCU on the sending unit can directly drive a transistor to operate the sending LED.

On the receiving end, however, you'll want to use an active filter circuit (band-selective amplifier) to amplify & band-pass filter your received signal, while blocking out extraneous noises.

After the amplify/filter stage, all that's left is to de-modulate your signal (using an envelope power measuring ADC for AM, OOK or PWM; or appropriate FM demodulation) and feed it into the receiving MCU.

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you expand a bit more on the RX side with the filters and band amplifiers? This was probably the one thing I was a bit stuck on understanding. Thanks!

Comment: @randynewfield, you'll have to decide on which encoding method you're going to use before a good answer can be given on receiving and demodulating. Also, that's worthy of being asked as a second, different question.

Comment: @randynewfield As a starting point, here's a link to a question where I posted a fully-functional nandpas-filtering amplifier for someone who was wanting to Rx a 60KHz signal from an antenna. For your photodiode, you'll likely have a higher-amplitude signal & likely a better signal-to-noise ratio, but the circuit would work as long as you tune the resonant tank(s) to your pulse frequency: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/214252/wwvb-antenna-reciever-1st-amplifier-stage-no-signal/214257?noredirect=1#comment460539_214257

Comment: Here is a link to a resource which will explain how to tune the tank circuit(s) to your chosen frequency: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-6/parallel-tank-circuit-resonance/ After the amplifier cleans up & boosts the power of your signal, any further steps will require you to decide what exact modulation method you will use before I can help you more.

Answer (score 1):

Most IR remote controls use a 36 kHz carrier, not 48 kHz. There are a few common protocols, with the most widely used probably being [RC-5](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC-5).

In RC-5 a 14 bit binary packet is first encoded using [Manchester coding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code). In Manchester coding the bits are encoded as transitions in a waveform: zero becomes low followed by a high, one becomes high followed by low. These transitions occur at constant intervals.

[image: Manchester]

The advantage of this system is that since bits are encoded as transitions that occur with predictable timing, the receiver can synchronize its own clock with the signal and recover the data.

The Manchester coded signal is then amplitude modulated on a 36 kHz carrier. In simpler terms when the coded signal is high, the infrared LEDs are pulsed on and off at a frequency of 36 kHz. When the coded signal is low, the LEDs are kept off. One coded bit is transmitted every 1.778 ms.

[image: rc5]

The receiver has a photodiode that is used for reception. The photodiode is typically behind an IR filter that allows only certain IR wavelengths to pass, reducing interference from sunlight and lamps. The photodiode current varies directly with ligh exposure, and tiny changes in this current are first amplified, then band-pass filtered (all frequencies besides those near 36 kHz are removed) and finally passed to an envelope detector. The envelope detector tracks and averages the amplitude of the signal, removing the modulation. An automatic gain control circuit adjusts the amplifier gain for the ambient light conditions.

The data is then recovered by looking for transitions in the signal. After each transition the receiver waits for a fixed delay of slightly less than 1.778 ms before listening for the next transition, in order to distinguish data from the "filler" transitions that occur between bits. After all bits have been received the command is processed.

This summarises how a common, relatively simple IR protocol works. RC-5 is clearly useless for transmitting anything but button presses on a remote, but it illustrates the technology well. There are faster protocols such as the IRDA variants, but they have a very short range as they employ no real modulation to the data. If you want to transfer lots of data relatively far using infrared, I would use [orthogonal frequency division multiplexing](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c7/Rc-5_protocol_details.jpg/663px-Rc-5_protocol_details.jpg) (with digital signal processing) for modulating the data.

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you expand more on the RX side for me. More so on the entire receiving unit before the data is passed to an ADC on a micro-controller for processing. How is a IR photodiode coupled with an amplifier and a band pass filter to produce the relative signal that needs to be processed?